# c++ language related to functions

Tags: c++builder

If void main is a user defined function then can we make any change in this user defined function. For eg: can we write/use void main1() in place of main()?

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking. Your question is tagged "c++builder", does that mean you are asking specifically in the context of Borland's C++ Builder product? Or just from a perspective of what the C++ standard says about functions named "main"?

Answer (score 0):

No. The program loader looks for main() as the starting point of a console application (WinMain() for Windows apps).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just call `main1()` inside `main()`.